# Xamarin.Forms: Disabling FlyoutItem and Changing Default Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, routes, url-routing, flyout, argumentexception

I have a Xamarin.Forms project with some FlyoutItems:

MyShell.xaml:

> ...     ...
>
> ```
> <FlyoutItem x:Name="Page1" IsEnabled="False" Title="xxxx xxxx" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" >
>     <ShellContent Route="Page1">
>         <local:Page1 Parameter="-1" />
>     </ShellContent>
> </FlyoutItem>
> <FlyoutItem x:Name="Page2" Title="Alle Reisen" Icon="icon_feed.png">
>     <ShellContent Route="Page2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
> </FlyoutItem>
> <FlyoutItem Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
>     <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
> </FlyoutItem>     ...     ...
> ```

FlyoutItem `Page1` should only be enabled when some condition is true, so in codebehind I set `IsEnabled` depending on my condition:

MyShell.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MyShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public MyShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page2), typeof(Page2));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page1), typeof(Page1));

        this.Page1.IsEnabled = <Some Condition>;
    }
...
...
}
```

If disabled, Page2 should pop up first instead of Page1. Obviously, this is not the case automatically. So I changed the code to

```
bool enabled = this.Page1.IsEnabled = <Some Condition>;
if (!enabled)
     this.CurrentItem = Page2;
```

This worked for me, but after some `GoToAsync(<Other Route>)` , `GoToAsync("..")` causes error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Ambiguous routes matched for:
> //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem7/IMPL_Page2/Page2/Page1 matches found:
> //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem7/IMPL_Page2/Page2/Page1,
> //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem7/IMPL_Page2/Page2/Page1 Parameter name: uri'

Obviously, my solution to set `this.CurrentItem` is not ok.

What is the correct solution to make Page2 popup first if Page1 is disabled? Can I change the Flyout Items order?

**Edit**

Perhaps the problem is that Page2 both is part of the Flyout Menu **and** sometimes is reached via the route (`GoToAsync("Page2")`). Then `GoToAsync("..")` causes this error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I defined identical routes twice:

1. In .XAML - the `Route` attribute **defines** (not uses) a route
2. In .cs - identical routes are defined by `Routing.RegisterRoute`

Solution: either rename `Route`s in XAML or delete definitions in .cs

Comment: 1. Yes, you can only register the Routes once using either XAML or .cs. 2. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.